# Redux and React-Naitve: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I'm trying to set ducks and sagas in my first react-native application. But whenever I'm trying to call duck function, I get a red screen say: **Cannot read property 'type' of undefined**

[image: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined]

Redux store is getting created but doesn't know why it's not taking action in the switch case.

Following code is from my ducks/auth.js

```
import { fromJS, List } from 'immutable';

const action = name => `/auth/${name}`;

export const LOGIN_REQUEST = action('LOGIN_REQUEST');

export const loginRequest = () => ({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST, });

export const FETCH_LOGIN_REQUEST = action('FETCH_LOGIN_REQUEST');
export const fetchLoginRequest = login => ({ type: FETCH_LOGIN_REQUEST, login });

const initialState = {
  token: null,
}

const auth = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('Hello Action: ', action.type);

  switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return state.set('token', action.login);

    default:
      console.log('Hello Auth Ducks Default')
      return state;
  }
};

export default auth;
```

Comment: What does your console.log(action.type) output? I'm assuming undefined?

Comment: @JRK

This is coming in action.type console:  @@redux/INITk.h.c.n.b.f

Comment: @JRK, It seems that `action` is `undefined`, so `action.type` throw an error. How do you call `auth` function? 
Removed your console.log, comment your switch, and give us the return of `console.dir(action)`

Comment: `Reducer “auth” returned undefined when handling “@@redux/INIT4.f.t.o.4” action. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state.` I'm getting the following error when I remove the switch case. and `console.dir(action)` is `undefined`

Comment: @AlexandreT you can check it by running the code. `https://github.com/rajdeepratan/naiudaan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In welcome.js change

`import loginRequest from '../ducks/auth.js';`

to

`import {loginRequest} from '../ducks/auth.js';`

`loginRequest` is a named export and not a default export.